# Gas is too high in contract

Tags: solidity, gas, gas-price, optimization

I have the following stake function that whenever I call it uses almost 100.000 gas. I did the usual stuff optimizing the code to use less gas like using `struct`s and `uint256`, but the gas price is still abnormally high.

Gas:101721
Transaction cost:101721

```
function stake(uint256 amount) external updateReward(_msgSender()) {
    require(amount > 0, "Cannot stake 0");
    totalStakeAmount = totalStakeAmount.add(amount);
    User storage _user = userInfo[_msgSender()];
    _user.stakeAmount = _user.stakeAmount.add(amount);
    emit Staked(_msgSender(), amount);
}

function unstake(uint256 amount) public updateReward(_msgSender()) {
    require(amount > 0, "Cannot withdraw 0");
    User storage _user = userInfo[_msgSender()];
    totalStakeAmount = totalStakeAmount.sub(amount);
    _user.stakeAmount = _user.stakeAmount.sub(amount);
    IERC20(stakeToken).safeTransfer(_msgSender(), amount);
    emit Unstaked(_msgSender(), amount);
}
```

Comment: can you show your Struct? 100000 gas is **not** a lot

Comment: @MajdTL 


  `struct User {
        uint256 stakeAmount;
        uint256 rewards;
        uint256 userRewardPerTokenPaid;
    }`

Comment: okay your struct is okay, as I said 100k seems okay, you do a lot of stuff, updateReward, change storage variable, transfer erc20Tokens.

Comment: What does `updateReward` do?

Answer (score 0):

Your contract looks like a Synthetix derivative. If that's the case, then `updateReward` is here: https://github.com/Synthetixio/synthetix/blob/develop/contracts/StakingRewards.sol#L152

The Synthetix contract uses a complicated staking algorithm. That means it's not very cheap to use. But the good thing is that the cost doesn't go up as the number of stakers goes up, so the usage costs are constant. This makes it truly scalable. You simply have to accept that or use some other staking algorithm - although I doubt there are many more efficient ones.